# Position not changing for mesh in animate() in THREE.js

Tags: animation, three.js, position, mutable

I'm trying to get a mesh's position to change constantly so that it moves at a constant velocity. The console shows that the position Vector3 is changing, but the actual scene shows all of the meshes remaining static. This is the code I tried:

```
let ball = new THREE.Mesh();
let equator = new THREE.Mesh()

for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

    let scale = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1

    let pos_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 5 - 25
    let pos_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 5 - 25
    let pos_z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 5 - 25
    pos = new THREE.Vector3(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)

    loader.load( './ball.gltf', function ( gltf ) { //load sphere
        gltf.scene.traverse(function(model) {
            if (model.isMesh) {
            model.castShadow = true;
            model.material = sphereMaterial;
            pos_arr.push(model)
            }
        });
        ball = gltf.scene
        ball.position.set(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        ball.scale.set(scale, scale, scale)
        scene.add( ball );
        
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    } );    

    loader.load( './equator.gltf', function ( gltf2 ) {
        gltf2.scene.traverse(function(model) { //for gltf shadows!
            if (model.isMesh) {
              model.castShadow = true
              model.material = equatorMaterial
            }
        });
        equator = gltf2.scene
        equator.position.set(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        equator.scale.set(scale, scale, scale)
        scene.add( equator )
        
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error )
    } );
    pos_arr.push([ball, equator, pos])
}

//light
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
scene.add( light );


let y_axis_dist = []
for (let j = 0; j < pos_arr.length; j++) {
    y_axis_dist.push(pos_arr[j][2].distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0, pos_arr[j][2].y , 0)))
}

//render

console.log(pos_arr)
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    pos_arr[0][1].position.x += 0.1
    console.log(pos_arr[0][1].position)
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate()
```

[image]

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: pos_arr.push([ball, equator, pos]) doesn’t really do much because at that point the GLTF files haven’t loaded. So ball and equator don’t exist yet, they’re just the blank Meshes you initiated at the top. You have to store their references inside their respective onload functions so they have the gltf data.

Comment: By any chance, how wouldn't the GLTF files have loaded? The push() method call was put in after both load() method calls

Comment: Because loading assets takes time. When using `gltf.load( xxx ); yyy;`: xxx happens **after** yyy, even though it was written before it. This is because the function inside `.load()` gets called after the asset has loaded, and a few moments have passed. I recommend you [watch some videos explaining the asynchronous nature of JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNDfsHQ5Gts)

Comment: Ok, I understand. How would I go about storing the references inside the onload functions?